# How do I get the svn client to use a different copy of SSL?

Tags: versions, svn, ssl

I was having an SSL issue with my SVN client. I saw online that it may be due to using an old version of OpenSSL. So I followed [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=411492) to build the latest version of OpenSSL. The latest version is now in `/opt/openssl/` but the old version still exists. How do I point `svn` to use the SSL in `/opt/openssl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of subversion included in Ubuntu 11.04 at least does not link with OpenSSL, but instead uses the [GnuTLS](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/) library:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/svn
...
        libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26 (0x00007fab1dd33000)
...
        libneon-gnutls.so.27 => /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27 (0x00007fab1d239000)
```

So compiling a new version of OpenSSL is not sufficient.  If you want Subversion to use it, you will probably have to recompile the Neon library and Subversion itself.

What makes you think that the SSL library is the cause of the problem you're seeing?  Perhaps there is some other solution to your problem aside from recompiling everything.